# new to JS, can someone help me understand why I cannot retrieve this value

Tags: javascript

I am wondering why I cannot retrieve the value in the alert function. I know the 'mainObj' is being created as I can test with an alert within the object constructor. but I can not access the child object properties. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
//used as a global
var theOBJ;

//child objects
function objChild(n,o,bgc){
    this.name = n;
    this.orientation = o;
    this.backgroundcolor = bgc;
}

//the Main Object
function objMain(n,o,bgc,ns){
    this.name = n;
    this.numsides = ns;
    if(this.numsides>2||this.numsides<1){
      alert("Number of sides are incorrect, setting to '1'"); 
      numsides=1;
    }
    child1 = new objChild(n+"_child1",o,bgc);
}


function createNewObject(n){
    //create a new Object
    theOBJ = new objMain(n,"landscape","",3);

    alert(theOBJ.child1.name);
}
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? This just defines a variable and three functions.

Comment: You are constructing.. you need to initialize !

Comment: well there is a lot of code. but this is all that is relevant

Comment: is this not where the object gets initialized? theOBJ = new objMain(n,"landscape","",3);

Comment: sorry,im not being smart with anyone. I really that that sending the parms with the function call and new keyword would initialize.

Comment: @michael it is. You just forgot something.

Comment: @michael If that is all the relevant code, then it can be shortened to nothing. That code literally does nothing.

Comment: @Onilol as you can see, constructing actually initialize an object.

Comment: @melpomene it takes a few seconds to find the problem here.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix If you make certain assumptions, yes.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix He defined and declared, he didn't initialize. There are no function calls :) Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345554/the-differences-between-initialize-define-declare-a-variable

Comment: well there has to be something wrong with the child1 initialization. I can remark that out and retrieve the name property of the main object in the alert.

Comment: Well, I'm more confused now. This worked as an assignment within the parent object: this.child1 = new objChild(n+"_child1",o,""); Then in the objChild object I added: alert("initialized"); The alert from the createNewObject function then returned the theOBJ.child1.name value. But I still do not understand why I need the alert in the objChild definition to push the functionality thru.

Comment: @Onilol he's calling the methods inside the `createNewObject`

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix there is no function **call** there , man.. He merely declared the var and the functions.

Comment: @Onilol the call to the constructor is in the `createNewObject` and how the `createNewObject(n)` is called doesn't matter in this case. Don't be so picky on a new user.

Comment: Thank you for your concerns. at this point there is just a "class" with no methods. I'm trying to organize my thoughts using a new language. I'm just not uncerstanding some things. Thanks for all the input. I'm sorry for confusing you with just the bare bones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not assigning the `child1` object to the `this` object in the `objMain` constructor. As it is defined without using `var` or being directly affected to `this` it could polute the global scope.

It should be :

```
 function objMain(n,o,bgc,ns){
    this.name = n;
    this.numsides = ns;
    if(this.numsides>2||this.numsides<1){
      alert("Number of sides are incorrect, setting to '1'");
      // <<< this line also needs a change >>>
      this.numsides=1;
    }
    // <<< this line >>>
    this.child1 = new objChild(n+"_child1",o,bgc);
 }
```

Comment: I did add the 'this' as that would make sense. however I'm still not retrieving the child objects' property.

Comment: Also, there is a second line in the if that is wrong. I missed it yesterday.