# Why can't I use a static block to initialize my static class member?

Tags: c++, static-members, static-initialization, static-block

(I was asked this question recently.)

I want to use the [C++ `static_block` construct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34321324/1593077) to initialize static
field of a class:

```c++
static_block {
   myns::foo my_foo;
   auto s = my_foo.from_string("null");
   if (s.good()) {
     std::string bar::transmogrified_foo = my_foo.transmogrify();
   } else {
     std::string bar::transmogrified_foo = "";
   }
}
```

where `transmogrified_foo` is declared in the class as:

```c++
static std::string transmogrified_foo;
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error: definition or redeclaration of 'transmogrified_foo' not allowed inside a function
```

Do you have suggestion how the static field should be initialized ?

Comment: It's essentially the same question as the beginner question: how come I write `int i = 1; if(something) {int i = 2;} cout<<i;` and something is true but it prints 1?

Comment: @user253751: For a lax enough definition of "essentially".

Comment: It's a *really* bad idea to assume that "<Some language> does this, so <Some other language> will do it that way too.".     While you may get lucky, as you have in this case, and get an observable difference - it's quite common that your code seems to work correctly until (sometime in the future) a minor edit causes an unexplained bug (and worse, a bug for an end user who gets grumpy about it, not yourself). JavaScript and C++ are *different* languages because they do things quite differently, even when using the same syntax (the syntax appears the same, the semantics/meaning differs).

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the *definition* of the static member with its *initialization*. See also:

[The differences between initialize, define, declare a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23345554/1593077)

It seems like you were trying to *define* your static field, when it has no other definition. Indeed, you can't do that within the body of a function (and a `static_block` actually invokes a static function).

You could do one of two things:

1. Split the definition and the initialization of the field - in which case you could initialize in a static block.
2. Use another way of running a bit of code when defining your field - not a static block.

I would go with option (2.) :

```
std::string bar::transmogrified_foo = 
   []() {
       myns::foo my_foo;
       auto s = my_foo.from_string("null");
       return s.good() ? my_foo.transmogrify() : "";
   }();
```

So, you see the static block doesn't really give you any benefit here.